# Put a digital clock in a pygtk window

Tags: python, pygtk, clock, glade

**Hello,**

**I have this code for a digital clock with TKinter:**

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import Tkinter
import time

def tick(time_old, clock):
    # get the current local time from the PC
    time_now = time.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
    # if time string has changed, update it
    if time_now != time_old:
        time_old = time_now
        clock.config(text = time_now)
    # calls itself every 200 milliseconds
    # to update the time display as needed
    # could use >200 ms, but display gets jerky
    clock.after(200, tick, time_old, clock)

def main():
    root = Tkinter.Tk()
    clock = Tkinter.Label(root, font=('times', 20, 'bold'), bg='green')
    clock.pack(fill=Tkinter.BOTH, expand=1)
    tick("", clock)
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

**The question is: ¿How I could put the TKinter.label centered in a pygtk window (in label2) (or glade)?**

**window code:**

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import pygtk
pygtk.require("2.0")
import gtk
import gtk.glade

class Principal:
    def __init__(self):    
        self.gladefile = "ejemplo.glade"
        self.glade = gtk.Builder()
        self.glade.add_from_file(self.gladefile)
        label2 = self.glade.get_object("label2")
        window = self.glade.get_object("ventana")
        window.set_keep_above(True)
        window.show_all()
        self.glade.connect_signals(self)  

    def on_ventana_delete_event(self, widget, event):
        gtk.main_quit()

    def on_boton_clicked(self, widget):
        self.glade.get_widget('label1').set_text('change title label')

    def on_boton2_clicked(self, widget):
        gtk.main_quit()    


if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        a = Principal()
        gtk.main()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass
```

**Glade code:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<interface>
  <requires lib="gtk+" version="2.16"/>
  <!-- interface-naming-policy project-wide -->
  <object class="GtkWindow" id="ventana">
    <property name="can_focus">False</property>
    <property name="title" translatable="yes">Ventana Principal</property>
    <property name="resizable">False</property>
    <property name="window_position">center-always</property>
    <property name="default_width">200</property>
    <property name="default_height">100</property>
    <property name="icon">Walker.png</property>
    <signal name="delete-event" handler="on_ventana_delete_event" swapped="no"/>
    <child>
      <object class="GtkHBox" id="hbox1">
        <property name="visible">True</property>
        <property name="can_focus">False</property>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkLabel" id="label1">
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can_focus">False</property>
            <property name="ypad">3</property>
            <property name="label" translatable="yes">Acción</property>
          </object>
          <packing>
            <property name="expand">False</property>
            <property name="fill">False</property>
            <property name="position">0</property>
          </packing>
        </child>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkButton" id="boton">
            <property name="label" translatable="yes">Cambiar label</property>
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can_focus">True</property>
            <property name="receives_default">True</property>
            <property name="use_action_appearance">False</property>
            <property name="xalign">0.54000002145767212</property>
            <signal name="clicked" handler="on_boton_clicked" swapped="no"/>
          </object>
          <packing>
            <property name="expand">False</property>
            <property name="fill">False</property>
            <property name="position">1</property>
          </packing>
        </child>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkLabel" id="label2">
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can_focus">False</property>
            <property name="label" translatable="yes">label</property>
          </object>
          <packing>
            <property name="expand">True</property>
            <property name="fill">True</property>
            <property name="position">2</property>
          </packing>
        </child>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkButton" id="boton2">
            <property name="label" translatable="yes">Salir</property>
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can_focus">True</property>
            <property name="receives_default">True</property>
            <property name="use_action_appearance">False</property>
            <signal name="clicked" handler="on_boton2_clicked" swapped="no"/>
          </object>
          <packing>
            <property name="expand">False</property>
            <property name="fill">False</property>
            <property name="position">3</property>
          </packing>
        </child>
      </object>
    </child>
  </object>
</interface>
```

**Thanks!**

Comment: I don't know your use case, but there is a very good chance this is going to be much more trouble than it's worth for you. That being said, [this](http://www.pygtk.org/pygtk2tutorial/sec-PlugsAndSockets.html) and [this](http://www.mail-archive.com/pygtk@daa.com.au/msg15746.html) might help you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I got you right, here's the code that will do the trick:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8  -*-

import pygtk
pygtk.require('2.0')
import gtk
import time

class Clock:

    def __init__(self):
        window = gtk.Window(gtk.WINDOW_TOPLEVEL)
        window.connect("destroy", lambda w: gtk.main_quit())
        window.set_title("Clock")
        self.label = gtk.Label()
        window.add(self.label)
        window.set_border_width(25)
        window.show_all ()

    def update(self):
        self.label.set_text(time.strftime('%H:%M:%S'))
        return True  #needed to keep the update method in the schedule

def main():
    gtk.main()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    clock = Clock()
    gtk.timeout_add(200, clock.update)  #add to the main loop scheduled tasks
    main()
```

Comment: Perfect! Exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the attributes of fonts

```
def update(self):
    self.label.set_markup("<span font_family='arial'weight='heavy'><big>" 
                          + time.strftime('%H:%M:%S') + 
                          "</big></span>")      
    return True  #needed to keep the update method in the schedule
```